# How can I Update cart item quantity with django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

hope someone will help me to fix my problem.
Since few time ago I am facing with a problem with my code, I couldn't understand why it's not working even that everything seem to be all ok for me. I want to give the possibility to update the cart quantity but I can only do it from the admin side not from a post request with a form.

I have already try many example I have found on internet but nothing seem to fix mine. when I am posting the the quantity, I can see the data I am posting from the terminal by doing print(request.POST) but the doesn't going to the admin to update the cart quantity.

Signal to save:

```
def m2m_changed_cart_receiver(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
print("hello depuis le model")
if action == 'post_add' or action == 'post_remove' or action == 'post_clear':
    bustravels = instance.bustravels.all()
    #busquantity = BusCart.objects.get(booking_seats_num=1)
    total = 0
    for x in bustravels:
        total += x.price
    if instance.subtotal != total:
        instance.subtotal = total
        instance.save()

  m2m_changed.connect(m2m_changed_cart_receiver, sender=BusCart.bustravels.through)

def pre_save_cart_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
if instance.subtotal > 0:
    instance.total = Decimal(instance.subtotal) * Decimal(1.015) # 1.5% tax
else:
    instance.total = 0.00

pre_save.connect(pre_save_cart_receiver, sender=BusCart)
```

Here is my models code:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
bustravels = models.ForeignKey(BusTravels, null=True,   on_delete='CASCADE')
bus_cart = models.ForeignKey(BusCart, null=True, on_delete='CASCADE')
booking_seats_num = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "This entry contains {} {}(s).".format(self.booking_seats_num, self.bustravels)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Entry)
def update_cart(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  item = instance.booking_seats_num * instance.bustravels.price
  instance.bus_cart.subtotal += item
  instance.bus_cart.booking_seats_num += instance.booking_seats_num
  instance.bus_cart.updated = datetime.now()
```

Cart model:

```
class BusCart(models.Model):
user                = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
bustravels          = models.ManyToManyField(BusTravels, blank=True)
booking_seats_num   = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
subtotal            = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
total               = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
updated             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
timestamp           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

objects = BusCartManager()
```

ModelManager:

```
class BusCartManager(models.Manager):
def bus_new_or_get(self, request):
    bus_cart_id = request.session.get('bus_cart_id', None)
    qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=bus_cart_id)
    if qs.count() == 1: 
        bus_new_obj = False
        bus_cart_obj = qs.first()
        if request.user.is_authenticated and bus_cart_obj.user is None:
            bus_cart_obj.user = request.user
            bus_cart_obj.save()
        #print("Cart id exists")
    else:
        bus_cart_obj = BusCart.objects.bus_new_cart(user=request.user)
        bus_new_obj = True
        request.session['bus_cart_id'] = bus_cart_obj.id
    return bus_cart_obj, bus_new_obj

def bus_new_cart(self, user=None):
    user_obj = None
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_authenticated:
            user_obj = user
    return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)
```

my modelForm to post the data:

```
class BusQuantityForm(forms.ModelForm):
PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1, 71)]
booking_seats_num = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Number of places', choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES, coerce=int, required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Entry
    fields = ['booking_seats_num',] #'bustravels', 'bus_cart', ]
```

and this is my view:

```
form = BusQuantityForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
# if request.method == 'POST':

if form.is_valid():
    print(request.POST)
    bus_travels_id = request.POST.get('bus_travels_id')
    booking_seats_num = request.POST.get('booking_seats_num')
    if bus_travels_id is not None:
        bus_cart_obj, bus_new_obj = BusCart.objects.bus_new_or_get(request)
        bus_travels_obj = BusTravels.objects.get(id=bus_travels_id)
        #Entry.objects.create(bus_cart=bus_cart_obj, bustravels=bus_travels_obj, booking_seats_num=booking_seats_num)
        # bus_cart_obj.bustravels.add(bus_travels_obj) # bus_cart_obj.bustravels.add(bus_travels_id)
        # added = True
        # bus_travels_id = request.POST.get('bus_travels_id')
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.booking_seats_num = booking_seats_num
        instance.bustravels = bus_travels_obj
        instance.bus_cart = bus_cart_obj
        instance.save()
```

and my templates is:

```
<td>
    <form action="{% url 'bus_cart_home' %}" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}  <input type="hidden" name="bustravels" value="{{ product }}" readonly>
   <input type="hidden" name="bus_cart" value="{{ bus_cart }}" readonly>
    {{ form.booking_seats_num|as_crispy_field }}
    <input type="submit" value="Updated" class="btn btn-info" style="background-color: #0c1836;">
   </form>
 </td>
```

As I said it I have try many way to fix this problem before I came here to ask a help for my problem, I have try many way but I still don't have what I want which is to update the cart quantity .

So any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: What's your problem ?

Comment: @gachdavit I can't add cart quantity when I post nothing go through the database bus I can see the post data from my terminal. this so strange

Comment: Nothing is create and save into the database.

Comment: ```bus_new_or_get``` what is this method ?

Comment: anyway, avoid ```Signal```. You are not call ```save()``` in ```Signal```, but even call it... it will raise ```RecursionError```. Just put signal logic in your views.

Comment: @gachdavit its from my modelmanager, please check my question again I just updated some code

Comment: Okay, but add logic in views.py and do not use signals here. Why it's problem for you ?

Comment: @gachdavit I have update my question again and put the signal logic.

Comment: in your ```form.is_valid()``` why you can not set correct value of ```booking_seats_num``` ? ```instance.booking_seats_num = NEW_VALUE``` ?

Comment: @gachdavit I am getting it here booking_seats_num = request.POST.get('booking_seats_num') by request.POST because the user should put the number of quantity he need.

Comment: ```request.POST.get('booking_seats_num')``` You are getting correct value here, yes ? maybe ```if bus_travels_id is not None``` returns ```False``` ? and ```if``` condition is not invoked.

Comment: @gachdavit look what I just got from the request.POST when I try to post the quantity:     <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['k9qJNCQUFEG8sVTOgD6E39EWTRvbjEERsMXhRSWXQsGi94448eRKk5x3yPkSXTyG'], 'bustravels': ['AL IZZA  Bus No. DA22921804BI'], 'bus_cart': [' Bus cart id: 298'], 'booking_seats_num': ['17']}>

Comment: Yes. You do not have ```bus_travel_id``` key in your ```request.POST``` ```QueryDict```.

Comment: Your logic is not called at all (As it was expected).

Comment: send ```bus_travels_id``` key from client with payload of change logic !

Comment: @gachdavit yeah I can see it but how can send it? I have try many thing and now I am blocking lol

Comment: Data is sent from browser. You should use ```Javascript``` or add additional ```<input />``` form.

Comment: @gachdavit I got it csrfmiddlewaretoken 
'bWtNZ8kZAEmsbamhRR351J4Hlq2n4j2qjz0l3oq2LsmCSjxxJsObiFXO0oR4IyWf'
bustravels 
'AL IZZA  Bus No. DA22921804BI'
bus_cart 
' Bus cart id: 298'
bus_travels_id 
'6'
booking_seats_num 
'14'

Comment: @gachdavit but now I have another: TypeError at /bookings/bus-cart
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'decimal.Decimal' from here: item = instance.booking_seats_num * instance.bustravels.price this from my model

Comment: @gachdavit I just fixed the problem and everything seem to work perfectly, I am so tired because I didn't sleep since yesterday lol. thank you very much.

Comment: It's fine. Have a nice life.